# How to implement session handling in Java to be servlet container independent?

Tags: java

AFAIK: [Session handling is done by the servlet Container](http://www.freeopenbook.com/mysqlcookbook/mysqlckbk-CHP-19-SECT-4.html) (e.g. Tomcat, Glassfish...), i would prefer a solution which is servlet container independent, like php does it, implement some handler or filter and let the application deal with it. I have not found any sort of Information regarding self build session handling in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The session handling is defined by the Servlet (JavaEE) specification if I'm not mistaken. If you want to hook into it's lifecyle you can do that with a [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html)

It seems that you can register your own session manager in Tomcat. Maybe that is what you are looking for: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html

But I fail to see why you want to replace a working, tested and solid implementation with your own code.

Comment: that was exactly what i was looking for! I need to share a session between different applications in different languages, and needed a way to implement it. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [example](https://github.com/dawsonsystems/Mongo-Tomcat-Sessions).

Comment: Thanks Umar, that an awesome resource to have :)

Comment: Here is another nice project based on memcache: http://code.google.com/p/memcached-session-manager/